# Expo, React-Native] "Failed prop type" error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-proptypes

I'm making a simple To DO App with react-native and expo xde.
This is my repo that makes error.(develop branch, commit 636543d125d8de2526c4fb7cd35d67d90638d397)
https://github.com/daengdaengLee/to-do-manager/tree/636543d125d8de2526c4fb7cd35d67d90638d397

When I run my project, it makes the error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: ActionButton: prop type `eventFunc` is invalid;
it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.
    in ActionButton (at App.js:45)
    ...
```

This is my App.js where makes the error:

```
...
render() {
  ...
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ActionButton // this is line 45. where the error occurs
        icon="❌"
        eventFunc={() => alert('event func')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
...
```

This is my ActionButton Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// import Components
import Button from '../../atoms/Button';
import MyView from '../../atoms/MyView';
import MyText from '../../atoms/MyText';

function ActionButton({ icon, eventFunc }) {
  return (
    <Button ownEvent={{ onPressOut: eventFunc }}>
      <MyView styleNames={['iconContainer']}>
        <MyText>
          {icon}
        </MyText>
      </MyView>
    </Button>
  );
}

ActionButton.propTypes = {
  eventFunc: PropTypes.func.isResquired,
  icon: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

export default ActionButton;
```

But something starnge is that the function `() => alert('event func')` is actually passed.
When I press out the Button, it makes the alert message 'event func' actually.
But the error message said that I'm not passing the function and `undefined` is passed.

What makes this weird situation?
Please Help me.
Thanks for reading. Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Instead of GitHub could you write some code directly in your question?  Should be smallest amount of code necessary to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in `ActionButton`: change `isResquired` to `isRequired`.

Comment: oh my god, I got it! Thanks so much. I was stupid...  Hava a nice Coding!